# If electromagnetic wave travels in a straight line how do you explain magnetic line of forces?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, virtual-particles

Imagine a piece of bar magnet and the presence of magnetic line of forces indicated by iron filings around the magnet, this magnetic line of force is compose of virtual photon right? and since magnetic line of force travels at speed of light in vacuum I don't understand why magnetic line of forces are bended? Are there virtual charged particles involved?

Comment: Magnetic field lines are solutions to a static equation, not travel paths for waves which are solutions to the wave equations.  Two different things.  From a classical p.o.v. the EM wave is not the static field line but a time dependent disturbance in the field.  It's that disturbance that propagates.

Comment: @ggcg: what is time dependent disturbance? this term is used in which theory so I can google it?

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question.  It is used in all wave theory.  EM waves are "waves", they obey the wave equation.  Field lines do not, they obey static, time independent equations.  A better question is how do static fields get set up in space at all when the field cannot travel from the source any faster than c.

Comment: @ggcg: is magnetic line of force a static magnetic field where many virtual photons are produced along this line?

Comment: @ggcg Your comments should have been an answer

Comment: @AaronStevens, maybe.  Oh well I'll post the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electric field lines are curved as well, for example this is what the field lines look like for an electric dipole:

[image: Electric dipole]

([image from Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/dipole.html))

The reason why field lines are curved while light travels in straight lines is because the two things are completely different. The field lines show the direction of the force on a positive test charge, and if more than one charge is present this force will be a vector sum of all the forces due to the charges and the direction will vary as you move closer and farther away from the different charges.

It is tempting to think of the field lines as showing the direction that the field flows, in a similar way that flow lines in a fluid show the direction the fluid is flowing. However this is not the case. The electrostatic (or magnet if this were a magnetic dipole) field is not flowing. The only thing moving would be the test charge we put into the field to determine its direction.

If you interpret the field lines as a flow I can see how it would seem odd that they move in curves, but since they don't show a flow the problem doesn't arise.

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic field lines are solutions to a static equation, not travel paths for waves which are solutions to the wave equations. Two different things. From a classical p.o.v. the EM wave is not the static field line but a time dependent disturbance in the field. It's that disturbance that propagates.  EM waves are "waves", they obey the wave equation. Field lines do not, they obey static, time independent equations. A better question is how do static fields get set up in space at all when the field cannot travel from the source any faster than c.